# Are error highlights and auto complete missing in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ide, data-science

I am learning data science for the first time. The course I am taking recommends to use Jupyter Notebook as IDE.

I can't find the feature of predetermining potential errors before running the code.

I used Sublime Text when I first learned Python, and if I'm remembering correctly Sublime Text underlined typos or undefined variables etc.

Is there a way to enable the feature in Jupyter Notebook?

I am curious as to why such an essential feature to an IDE is missing in Jupyter Notebook.

++ I also just noticed that auto-complete feature is missing as well.

Comment: There are some extensions for notebook, some of them might do what you want, though it's not the full capabilities of an IDE: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are extensions to jupyter:

you'd get lots of them by running

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter contrib nbextension install
```

Now when you run jupyter, you'd have a new Nbextensions tab where you can select which extension to use.

There's a spelling extension there, but I didn't see a "possible error highlight" extension there, but there's [this extension](https://github.com/mlshapiro/jupyterlab-flake8) which does that.